# FragmentManager has not been attached to a host error while running an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im new to android and they(some people :) ) gave me an half developed app and im still confused about some things.
Im getting an error which i can't understand what it means. So the error is what i wrote in the title : java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has not been attached to a host, and is hapening when this activity runs:

```
package com.example.loginregistodb;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ClienteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Spinner tipo_intervencao;
Button bt_cliente_seguinte;
EditText et_inserir_cliente;
ImageView icon1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cliente);

    bt_cliente_seguinte = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_cliente_seguinte);
    et_inserir_cliente = findViewById(R.id.et_inserir_cliente);
    tipo_intervencao = findViewById(R.id.tipo_intervencao);
    icon1 = findViewById(R.id.icon2);

    bt_cliente_seguinte.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String cliente = et_inserir_cliente.getText().toString();
            String tipoIntervencao = "" + tipo_intervencao.getSelectedItem().toString();
            preencherExcel Excel = new preencherExcel();
            Excel.entradaWhatsapp(cliente, tipoIntervencao);

            if (cliente.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                Toast.makeText(ClienteActivity.this, "Preencha o campo Cliente!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(ClienteActivity.this, EmpresaActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

EDIT :
the error message i get is this :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.loginregistodb, PID: 15275
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has not been attached to a host.
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1938)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1996)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:600)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ActivityScope.lambda$onFragmentActivityStopCallOnce$1(ActivityScope.java:180)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ActivityScope$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: There is nothing about Fragment here....neither the complete Error/Exception. Without enough information it's difficult to help you somehow.

Comment: i just posted the errors that shows when the activity runs 
i rly understand much about the problem that why i dont know if its something elsewhere, but the app crashes when i run this activity and those errors are the only info that shows

Comment: Ok but unfortunately in your code there isn't any reference to Fragment, FragmentManager, Firebase or other things written in the Error Log, so the error cannot be in these few lines of code. Maybe in one of those METHODS (like "entradaWhatsapp()") or in called EmpresaActivity. I don't know where it could be without see more code that involves one of prev (in this comment few lines above) Classes and how you use them.

Comment: ok, i'll search for fragments related stuff in the mothods used in this class
Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: JUst tell me one thing, when this error occurs, what kind of problems usually cause this?

Comment: You have to read this log upside-down: it seems that an Activity ("ActivityThread.java:7656") tried to call something about Firebase ("com.google.firebase.firestore") (which is used for Analytics, Cloud Storage and other online Google services) which tries to interact with FragmentManager (FragmentManager.java) but I don't see anything about any of these things in your code. In your code I can see an Activity that executes some Method when a button is clicked. Nothing more.

Comment: Exactly, thats what is suposed to be, its like a sub-menu of the app that leads me to other activity (another sub-menu) 
In the activity called next ("EmpresaActivity") there's nothing about fragments either, and in the methods used here theres nothing about fragmentManager to so i dont understand why is it crashing here when  this activity is just as simple as it is xd

Comment: Try remaking the activity.